# Any command we can use to convert windows file to unix or mac file?

Tags: linux, perl

I don't want to use dos2unix tool. I want to use command in Ubuntu terminal to convert Windows file to Unix file. Is that possible. I have looked through other articles and tried those commands but none working. Anyone can help?

Comment: *Why* don't you want to use dos2unix, the tool that was built specifically for this purpose?

Comment: I am using Activestate Perl in my windows and my perl script running well in my windows but I need to make this script to work on MAC. So I have installed Ubuntu in my pendrive and working from there. I can't install dos2unix, so I am looking for if there is any way I can convert my windows files to unix files using terminal command only?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `tr` to remove carriage returns like this:

```
tr -d '\r' < WindowsFile > UnixFile
```

You can use

```
cat -vet WindowsFile
```

to see if there are carriage returns in your file and they'll show up as `^M`

Comment: It didn't convert the file.

Answer (score 4):

> I want to use command in Ubuntu terminal to convert Windows file to Unix file.

```
dos2unix path/to/file/to/convert
```

> I don't want to use dos2unix tool.

```
alias notdos2unix=dos2unix

notdos2unix path/to/file/to/convert
```

Comment: @JS웃, If one doesn't specify why one doesn't want to use something, then how can we judge what would be a suitable alternative? As far as we know, he doesn't like the name. What's worse is the reason for wanting to avoid the something is usually flawed and something that we can help with (e.g. installing a module).

Comment: Made me burst out laughing +1

Answer (score 3):

For Ubuntu(and Debian) you can use the tofrodos package.

```
sudo aptitude install tofrodos
fromdos file.txt # converts the file to UNIX line-endings
todos   file.txt # converts the file to Windows line-endings
```

OSX (being a derivative of UNIX) should have the same line-endings as UNIX.

If you're on Windows, you can find [tofrodos binaries here](http://www.thefreecountry.com/tofrodos/).

If you're on a Mac, you can use the [brew](http://brew.sh/) package manager and install the [tofrodos](http://braumeister.org/formula/tofrodos) on OSX.