# Replace empty field at the end of line using awk

Tags: bash, awk, gsub, string-substitution

I am stuck. Say I have tab separated file with 4 columns.

```
A326931873  2014-10-26 09:55:28.000 N06 D00030131051410
A326931902  2014-10-26 09:56:10.000 N06
```

And want to replace empty field at the end of the line with \N. The result should be

```
A326931873  2014-10-26 09:55:28.000 N06 D00030131051410
A326931902  2014-10-26 09:56:10.000 N06 \N
```

I have tried `awk -F'\t' 'BEGIN {sub("", "\N", $4); print}' file`, `awk -F'\t' 'BEGIN {sub(/^&/, "\N", $4); print}' file` and alike with no luck.

**Update1**: As suggested I have also tried using number of fields, but `awk -F"\t" 'NF<4 {print}' file` returns no results, that is all lines have four fields.

**Update2**: `cat -vET file` shows

```
A326931873^I2014-10-26 09:55:28.000^IN06^ID00030131051410^M$
A326931902^I2014-10-26 09:56:10.000^IN06^I^M$
```

**Update3**: after removing carriage returns `cat -vET file` shows

```
A326931873^I2014-10-26 09:55:28.000^IN06^ID00030131051410$
A326931902^I2014-10-26 09:56:10.000^IN06^I$
```

and any of the suggested solutions does not work.

Comment: You have a DOS file. To work with it you can try with `dos2unix`. Check this answer also: [Any command we can use to convert windows file to unix or mac file?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23255571/1983854).

Comment: It is not a problem in the solutions but in your input. Clean it with the previous links and maybe also http://stackoverflow.com/a/20601044/1983854

Answer (score 2):

I assume that for the line with empty `$4`, there was a trailing `<tab>`
try this line:

```
awk -F'\t' '$NF=!$NF?"\\N":$NF' file
```

If there is no `<tab>` before the empty field:

```
awk -F'\t' -v OFS="\t" 'NF==3{$4="\\N"}7' file
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know how many fields there should be, you can provide that value to the script.

Then, in case the current line has less fields you can append this given text as the last one:

```
awk -v fields=5 -F"\t" 'NF<fields {$fields="\\N"} 1' file
```

For your given input it returns:

```
A326931873 2014-10-26 09:55:28.000 N06 D00030131051410
A326931902 2014-10-26 09:56:10.000 N06 \N
```

Notes:

- this works because `NF` stands for **N**umber of **f**ields, so that it indicates how many fields the current line has.
- we have to say `$fields="\\N"` because `\` needs to be escaped to be handled properly. Otherwise, if you just use `\N`, you might get an error like this:

> warning: escape sequence `\N' treated as plain`N'

Answer (score 1):

You can use  a very simple format like

```
$ awk 'NF<5{$5="\\N"}1' temp
A326931873  2014-10-26 09:55:28.000 N06 D00030131051410
A326931902 2014-10-26 09:56:10.000 N06 \N
```

Answer (score 0):

So I have figured out the answer myself `awk -F'\t' -v OFS='\t' 'length($4)==1{$4="\N"}1' file`

Comment: I doubt `$4="\N"` works. See my answer to understand why you need to use `\\N`.